# Why doesn't this KroneckerDelta simplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

When I take `D[Sum[a[x[0], x[j]], {j, 1, nsp}], x[0]]` I get

[image]

I would expect that the `KroneckerDelta[0, j]` would automatically simplify to zero since `j` ranges from `1` to `nsp` in the sum, but no luck, even applying  `FullSimplify[D[Sum[a[x[0], x[j]] n[j], {j, 1, nsp}], x[0]], j > 0]`.

Any idea on how to eliminate this term, short of applying `/.KroneckerDelta[0, _]->0` after the fact?

**Addendum:**

Also, while you're reading, why does `D[Sum[a[x[i], x[j]], {j, 1, nsp}], x[i]]` take significantly longer than `D[Sum[a[x[0], x[j]], {j, 1, nsp}], x[0]]`, and why do these run 100x faster when re-run?

Comment: If you look at the `FullForm` of the output, it's of the form `Sum[Plus[a, b], List[j, 1, nsp]]`, where `a` and `b` are the two parts of your summand above.  If you then tell Mathematica to find `Sum[a, List[j,1,nsp]]`, it returns `0`.  So if you can tell Mathematica to replace `Sum[Plus[a,b]]` with `Sum[a] + Sum[b]` (more or less), you'd be good to go.  My pattern-matching skills aren't strong enough to know how to do this automatically with replacement rules, though.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks, `D[Sum[a[x[0], x[j]], {j, 1, nsp}], x[0]] /. Unevaluated[Sum[a_ + b_, range_List] -> Sum[a, range] + Sum[b, range]]` seems to work, although I think a better solution for me will be to use a different variable than `x[0]` in the first place.

Comment: Another solution: `Distribute[D[Sum[a[x[0], x[j]], {j, 1, nsp}], x[0]]]`